# Problem with: source env/bin/activate

Tags: bash, python, vmware

I am using ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to run Oyente tool for which I have to use Python.

I found the following link:

[How to use Oyente...](https://medium.com/haloblock/how-to-use-oyente-a-smart-contract-security-analyzer-solidity-tutorial-86671be93c4b)

I am getting error at the following command:

```
@lc2530hz:~$ source env/bin/activate
```

bash: env/bin/activate: No such file or directory

I don't have "env" directory. Should I create the directory. I found several links for the above error but each link is using a different. I can't understand their solution. Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From that guide, you're creating a Python virtual environment:

```
python -m virtualenv envsp
source env/bin/activate
```

Using the above, you're creating a folder called `envsp` which will hold your virtual env.

To enter it, use:
`source envsp/bin/activate`

Seems like just a typo in the guide.

Comment: Good. God bless you. Zulfi.